# GCSFuse using local disk space

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I am having an issue with a bucket mounted on a GCP VM using gcsfuse. Based on the documentation :

> Note that new and modified files are also fully staged in the local temporary directory until they are written out to GCS due to being closed or fsync'd. Therefore the user must ensure that there is enough free space available to handle staged content when writing large files.

However we need to make huge amounts of backups. Is there a way to manually force this sync in order to clear out the disk space or even to specify the disk that it needs to use for this temporary files? At the moment it is using the root OS disk and runs out of space, while we have a 5TB disk that we can use for this

Comment: Have you tried using the `--temp-dir` flag to change the location of the temp directory?